# Radgrid Control Problem

Tags: grid, rad

I have a Rad Grid taht have radiobutton as control. Depending on the radio button value selected, I want to make a panel outside the radgrid visble true or false. On clicking the rad grid control I am able to call function in code behind. Through code behind I am able to set the pannel visblity but it doesn't gets reflected in my web page.

Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by any change use telerik ajax manager or panel in this case? If so, make sure that your external panel is inside the RadAjaxPanel along with the grid or that you update the panel from the grid via RadAjaxManager setting.